# Truncate AWS logs using parse command

Tags: substr, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm having some hard time making a easy AWS Logs Insights statement. At the moment I have it like this:

```
filter @message like /product-id/
| parse "product_id=" as id
```

The point that I want to achieve is to only have the product-ids, nothing else after that in the id column. The product-id is at the moment a 10 character long string, followed by some other logs values that I am not currently interested in.

I know that i have to use the substr function but haven't managed to integrate it into my search statement in AWS Cloudwatch.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share an extract of your log?